# Code stopping somewhere in `while True` loop, does not throw error or exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am making an app that tracks how long someone has been logged in for. It was working fine earlier, but it is having issues now, and I can't understand why.

The code provided is called using multiprocessing `mp.Process()`, where `parent` is a `class` object, `id` is an `int` that provides the session's ID number, and `shared_bool` is `mp.Value('b', True)`, creating a variable that can be shared between the parent and child process. In this case, `parent.Interface.write()` is a custom function from a self-made library that is meant to interact with google sheets, and I do not believe it plays a part in this error.

It should be noted that in `parent.Interface.write()`, the `silent` argument keeps this specific function from printing anything in console. I tried setting it to `False` to see if it would print anything, and it did not.

In the code below I've set it up so that it can `print` as it goes, to see where it gets frozen. Below the code will be everything it printed into console.

```
def track_login_time(parent, id, shared_bool):  # internal
        itn = 0
        print('Running.')
        while True:
            itn += 1
            print(f'Checking {itn}')
            time.sleep(1)
            with shared_bool.get_lock():
                if shared_bool.value:
                    print(f'Attempting {itn}')
                    if itn % 10 == 0:
                        print(f'Writing {itn}')
                        current_time = datetime.now()
                        session_time = current_time - parent.login_date
                        write_data = [str(current_time), str(session_time)]
                        parent.Interface.write([write_data], f'Logs!G{id+1}:H{id+1}', sheet_id=parent.vsid, silent=True)
                else:
                    print('Exiting. 1')
                    exit(12)
                if not dpg.is_dearpygui_running():
                    print('Exiting. 2')
                    exit(12)
```

The output to the console is as follows:

```
Running.
Checking 1
Attempting 1
```

After this, it ceases to print anything. The parent process will continue doing whatever it is doing, but the child process does not print anything else, and never makes it to `parent.Interface.write()`, which is the whole purpose of the child process.

The only place where `shared_bool` is set to `False` is in the `logout` function, which currently is not called anywhere in the program. This is the only way the child process can be killed manually. If the `dearpygui` window the app is made in stops running, it should kill the child process with the `dpg.is_dearpygui_running()` line. Whenever I kill the `dpg` window, the program terminates immediately without printing anything in console, implying that the child process was already terminated.

Comment: Logically, it seems to me that it is stuck in `dpg.is_dearpygui_running()`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I removed it and this did fix the issue, though I'm not sure how or why it would get stuck there.  Is there a way to have that code included so the process can end itself when `dpg.is_dearpygui_running()` is False while also avoiding this issue? I'm confused on how it got stuck there especially when it never printed "Exiting. 2", implying that it got into that code block.

Comment: It never printed "Exiting" *because* it got stuck in the line before that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I see, I'm probably just misunderstanding how it works then. If you wouldn't mind helping me out with that, since I couldn't find it with a quick glance at the [documentation](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/what-why.html), assuming you already understand how it works. If not I'll figure it out eventually, thank you.